# RazorGenerator, UsePhysicalViewsIfNewer and performance

Tags: razorgenerator

Has anyone tested UsePhysicalViewsIfNewer on a big system with lots of Views (thousands)?

If it has to check the disk each time doesn't make this slower? Does switching it off have any appreciable impact?

Answer (score 1):

It's designed to be a dev-time feature (in particular if you're using `RazorGenerator.MsBuild`). It's meant to stop you from having to rebuild the application every time you change a view. I haven't tried using it in a real-world application, but turning it off in a production app should be the right thing to do.